# ¿Es gramaticalmente correcta la frase "Extraño una parte de mí"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, gramática, verbos

He encontrado esta frase:

> Extraño una parte de mí, esa que se fue contigo.

Me parece que "Extraño una parte de mí" es una estructura gramaticalmente incorrecta.

¿Qué pensáis?

Comment: No es *extraño* como sinónimo de *raro*  sino del verbo [extrañar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HOuhHvr)

Comment: Eso es lo que me parecía, pero alguien me dijo que no ! Asi es la misma cosa de decir : **Falta una parte de mi** ?

Comment: Como dice @walen, la filosofía del sitio requiere un poco de esfuerzo previo a la hora de preguntar. Consulta las secciones [ask] y [tour] para más información. En todo caso, sé bienvenido, y por favor consúltanos cualquier duda que te surja.

Comment: Bienvenido @Tagadac. Para adicionar a los comentarios anteriores después de que leas [How to ask](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) por favor completa tu perfil. Para mejor responder tus preguntas algunas veces es bueno saber tu país de origen y tu nivel de español si es que no es tu lengua nativa.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consultando "extraño" en el diccionario, podrás ver que además de un adjetivo, también puede ser la primera persona del verbo **extrañar**:

> **[extrañar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HOuhHvr)**
>
> 2. tr. Echar de menos a alguien o algo, sentir su falta. *Lloraba el niño extrañando a sus padres.*

Que, en su segunda acepcion, significa "echar de menos". La frase se puede escribir como:

> Echo de menos una parte de mí, esa que se fue contigo.

No hay nada gramaticalmente anormal ni incorrecto en esta oración, es perfectamente válida.

Otra cosa es que sea más o menos difícil entender el significado. Está claro que a quien eso dice no le falta un trozo de cuerpo; lo que quiere decir esta persona es que, al irse la otra, se siente incompleta.

Veo que en tu pregunta no indicas *por qué* te parece incorrecta esa estructura. ¿Podrías comentar qué le ves de extraño?